# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'toArray' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I am using `hashset.toArray()[x]` to display a element in the jsf view, and this is working fine in my machine. 
But when I move this on to test server, the above error is thrown.

Both machines are running tomcat 7.

what is causing this error?

Comment: version of Hibernate on local and on Test server? Also JSF version on local and on test?

Comment: It's weird, because the message is correct. A `PersistentSet` has a *method* `toArray`, not a *property*. The EL is actually trying to access the property `getToArray()` and the result is an exception. Please show us the code that's working on your machine (jsf + bean). Using it in a display tag shouldn't actually work AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to invoke arbitrary non-property-related methods in EL is introduced in EL version 2.2 which goes hand in hand with Servlet 3.0. This feature didn't exist in older versions like Servlet 2.5 / EL 2.1.

So, if you deploy your webapp to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` root declaration, then it will work fine. However, if you deploy your webapp to a container of an older version, or with a `web.xml` which dictates an older version, or have dropped arbitrary container-specific JAR files of an older version inside webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` or even server's own `/lib`, then this feature won't work.

Provided that you're absolutely positive that the test server is running Tomcat 7 and thus not Tomcat 6 or so, then that can only mean that the `web.xml` was been changed to dictate an older version, or that your webapp or server's `/lib` is littered with arbitrary container-specific JAR files such as `jsp-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, etc which would only conflict with container's own libraries (this is often done by ignorant starters in order to workaround compilation errors they face in their IDE; which should have been solved [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/)).

Comment: Thanks Balusc for detailed answer